# Datetime Converting two times not equal starting time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, xunit

I'm using the [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) NuGet package.

The Pacific standart time is use UTC-8

1. Created a datetime as pacific timezone.
2. The pacific time converted utc time.
3. The utc time converted again to pacific timezone. But the result doesnt equal datetime in the first item. Why? Any idea?

```
[Fact]
public void DateTimeConvertTesting()
{
    TimeZoneInfo pacificTimeZone = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Pacific Standard Time"); // TimeZoneConverter
    DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffsetPacific2 = new DateTimeOffset(2021, 09, 01, 11, 59, 0, pacificTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset);
    DateTime utcDateTime = dateTimeOffsetPacific2.UtcDateTime;
    DateTime pacificTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, pacificTimeZone);
    Assert.True(dateTimeOffsetPacific2.DateTime == pacificTime);
}
```

Comment: Your question contains numerous conversions. For the end result to be unexpected, of the previous results must be unexpected. Can you narrow it down and indicate which step you think is incorrect?

Comment: I suspect it's going wrong because of a lack of DST awareness at some point of the process; you'll notice that your Assert is `True` if you change the September to March, and if you print the actual times out (when starting from september) your starting time of 11:59 ends up 1 hour out after conversion back from UTC..

Comment: Yes.  Keep in mind that `"Pacific Standard Time"` on the first line inside the method is the Windows time zone identifier for the US Pacific time zone, inclusive of DST when applicable.  While PST typically means UTC-8, the Pacific time zone alternates between UTC-8 and UTC-7, and the `TimeZoneInfo` object is aware of them both as well as the transitions between them.  Mentally remove the word "Standard" from the ID and it should make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Caius Jard hits the correct issue on the comment.

Looks like for [Pacific Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst) on 2021, [DST started March 14 02:00 AM and ends 7 November 02:00 AM](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pacific%20Standard%20Time%202021%20dst).

[`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc?view=net-6.0) handles the daylight saving *itself*. That means, if the `Datetime` or `DateTimeOffset` is a DST on `Pacific Standard Time`, it returns the DST added value (which is 1 hour usually). That's why your `pacificTime` variable
will be `{9/1/2021 12:59:00 PM}` *not* `{9/1/2021 11:59:00 PM}`

If you have to use `ConvertTimeFromUtc` for your test, it would be better to check first your `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` is a daylight saving time or not for *that* specific timezone. You can use [`TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime?view=net-6.0) method for that which have overloads both `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`.

```
var isDaylightSavingTime = pacificTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(utcDateTime);
// for 2021, 09, 01, 11, 59, 0, this returns true.
```